# See which directory takes space without considering other mountpoints

Tags: linux, unix, shell, directory

I often find myself having to clean up some directories because they are too full. Let's take `/var` as an example, as it is a common one, for obvious reasons.

In order to see which sub-directories takes a lot of space, I use `du -sh /var/*`. Unfortunately, I have some huge data in sub-directories of `/var`, which happen to be hosted on other partitions than `/var` (e.g. `/var/chroot`) and greatly slow the process for nothing.

Now `du` has a `-x` flag which excludes other mountpoints. It works fine when doing a `du -shx /var` but not with `du -shx /var/*` since `*` is expanded by the shell so `/var/chroot` is explicitely sent to `du`.

Another option I was proposed was to use `find /var -xdev -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec du -sh {} \+` but again, even though find does not *follow* other mountpoints, it still *prints* them and passes them to `du`, hence failing again to achieve my goal.

Before I end up writing a horrible bash function (or a perl/python program) that parses `df` or `mount` in a loop, does anyone know of a clean way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it looks like what you need is this:

```
du -hx --max-depth 1 /var
```

Comment: Ok, you posted your answer right as I was answering myself, so you get the vote :-) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from a colleague:

`du -hx --max-depth=1 /var`

does the trick.